# How do I set a column not to scroll till it encounters a value in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, scrolling, microsoft-office-2010

I have a table like as attached (similar, but on a much bigger scale):

[image]

I want to set it up such that when I scroll down column B, cell A2 with the value "A" remains displayed at the top, until the cell A5 with the value "B" reaches the top. At that point, the top cell should be cell A5 with the value "B", till the scrolling proceeds to the value "C" (cell A10), and so on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, not really. Even when splitting the window or freezing panes, Excel will always scroll complete rows. It is not possible to freeze part of a row to a cell that has a value.

Consider repeating the values in the blank cells below, so the visible rows will always show the current value in column A.

Here is a tip to quickly fill in the blank cells:

- select column A
- hit F5 to open the "Go To" dialog
- click Special
- tick "Blanks" and hit OK
- Now all blank cells are selected
- type a = sign
- hit the up arrow
- hold down the Ctrl key and hit Enter
- now each previously blank cell contains a formula that pulls the value from the cell above
- Select column A again and copy it
- use Paste Special > Values to replace the formula with the text that it returns