# Filling the blanks in a column with the same value till there is change in value in the column in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know if there is any solution to my problem

I have a sheet in certain format but i want it to be converted into different format

[image]

Comment: See this thread..https://superuser.com/questions/1228741/how-do-i-set-a-column-not-to-scroll-till-it-encounters-a-value-in-microsoft-exce

Answer (score 0):

In columns F-I, you can use an IF statement to check if the equivalent cell in columns A-D is blank; if it is blank use the value from the cell above, otherwise use the equivalent cell.

In cell F2, enter

```
=IF(A2="",F1,A2)
```

and copy that formula to the rest of the range F2:I9.