# Adding missing dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Have a couple hundred thousand lines of transaction data covering a 4 year period. Need complete data in a date column, but only one date is entered for all subsequent transactions (possibly hundreds) on that day... I need to get the date into each line so I can sort, pivot, etc., but obviously don’t want to manually copy and paste up to a 1000 different dates into nearly 300k cells.  Maybe a new column with an if/then statement that enters the date beside if not blank and skips upwards to the next non-blank cell and enters that date if it is blank, but I don’t know how to do this.

Comment: Check this answer and see if this is something what you are looking for. https://superuser.com/questions/1228741/how-do-i-set-a-column-not-to-scroll-till-it-encounters-a-value-in-microsoft-exce

Comment: Could you share portion of Source data for better understanding and the OUTPUT also. !! I guess you have several entries for Date Particular at Source and you want that Date to print once along with all transactions in adjacent column as output. ☺

Answer (score 1):

The formula you can use is very straightforward, exactly as you described it in your question. Just to illustrate, let's assume your data witht the dates starts in A1.

- Add one additional column (B).
- In cell B1, copy the content of cell A1 : `=A1`
- In cell B2, put `=IF(A2="";B1;A2)`
- Now you can copy the formula in B2 down to the end of your data

This will work based on two conditions:
(1) your data must be sorted on date (obviously)
(2) when there is no date, the cell must be **empty** (so the test `=""` yields `TRUE`. If the cell contains other characters (spaces or other invisible characters), you have to make the test a bit more complex.

Comment: After you do this, I would ***strongly recommend*** copying all of B:B and pasting as values. Otherwise, this will all be lost if you ever sort anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario when Helper Columns are not hidden:**

[image]

**Scenario when Helper Columns are hidden:**
[image]

*I'm assuming that you have source data in Range `A3:B12`.*

**How it works:**

1. For Helper Column 1 write this Formula in Cell `D3` & fill down.

   ```
    =INDEX(A3,1,1)
   ```
2. For Helper Column 2 write this Formula in Cell `E3` & fill down.

   ```
    =COUNTIF($D$3:$D3,D3)
   ```
3. In Cell `F3` write this formula & fill down to  generate Dates.

   ```
    =IF(D3=D2,"",D3)
   ```
4. Write this Array Formula in Cell `H3` & fill down.

   ```
    {=INDEX($B$3:$B$12, SMALL(IF($D3=$A$3:$A$12, ROW($A$3:$A$12)-MIN(ROW($A$3:$A$12))+1, ""), E3))}
   ```

**Note:**

- Finish the Array Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.